# Average of last 10 cell with data from bottom to the top with array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the average of the last 10 years with data for each year with the least "helper" columns, so in the example here, I want to be able to calculate the average of 133.91, 84.4, 92, 88.6, 118.3, 73.7, 103.2, 54,882.4 and 79.5 for year 2023 and for the year 2022, 84.4, 92, 88.6, 118.3, 73.7, 103.2, 54,882.4 and 79.5, 81.5 without having to use 2-3 helper columns and sorting my data differently as I need it to stay in chronological order for other formula. I'd like to be able to just slide down that formula to calculate the average for every year.

I tried a combination of map and index (to reverse the order of the data) array function, and vstack and scan function but I believe I might not be using them correctly.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Please update your question, show your input data and then show your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt, not a very elegant formula but does the job

Using the original data set, in Cell C1, enter the following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(LET(Rng_B,LET(Rng_A,OFFSET($B1,,,-MIN(ROW(),100)),FILTER(Rng_A,NOT(ISERR(Rng_A)))),DROP(Rng_B,MAX(0,COUNT(Rng_B)-10))))
```

Drag it down to get the average of the last 10 valid values

[image: Example Solution]

So a little explanation here,

Firstly, find the last 10 valid values, using this formula

```
LET(Rng_A,OFFSET($B1,,,-MIN(ROW(),100)),FILTER(Rng_A,NOT(ISERR(Rng_A))))
```

I used the LET function to avoid writing the same OFFSET formula multiple times. I have given a name, Rng_A, to this range, assuming the consecutive errors in column B are less than 100 times (if not, you could change 100 to a desired limit).

Secondly, pick the last 10 values from Rng_A using the DROP function.

```
DROP(Rng_B,MAX(0,COUNT(Rng_B)-10))
```

I used the LET function again to avoid writing the first LET function again in the DROP function. I gave another name, Rng_B, for the filtered range.

Lastly, find the average of Rng_B by using the AVERAGE function.

Feel free to leave me any suggestions that may simplify my formula. Happy to learn :]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data were located in cells as per the below screenshot
[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested formula]
you could use this formula

```
=LET(dat,TOCOL(B$1:B12,3),AVERAGE(CHOOSEROWS(dat,SEQUENCE(10,,ROWS(dat)-9,1))))
```

in `C12` and copy down as needed.

Comment: I like your idea of using `CHOOSEROWS` - but it will return wrong values if you use this formula e.g. for 2011 as `ROWS(dat) -9` will return a negative start value for `SEQUENCE` which will result in duplicate values. Furthermore - and this is propably really critical - by removing the errors from column B (your `dat`-variable) - your formula will include 2012 and 2013 in the average for 2023 - as the rows for 2016 and 2019 are omitted ...

Comment: @Ike I'm aware of how `CHOOSEROWS()` works - the OP asked for "the average of the last 10 years _with data_" and 2022 is the _first_ year to satisfy that test

Comment: "the average of the last 10 years with data" - ah ok, read too "fast" - your are right.

Comment: a good solution except it can only start in row 12 onward

Comment: @TerryW row 12 _is_ where the first year to meet the requirement (for the last 10 years with data) actually occurs

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You can use this formula in a table (Insert > Table) - it will automatically expand whenever new rows are added. Or - w/o table: drag it down

This approach takes care of the requirement "last 10 years with data".
It `TAKE`s the last 10 rows of the filtered result - or if less then 10 rows: all of them

```vb
= LET(filteredData,FILTER([Value],(ROW([Value])<=ROW())*(ISERROR([Value])=FALSE)),
      last10,TAKE(filteredData, -MIN(10,ROWS(filteredData))),
      AVERAGE(last10))
```

[image]

**First solution - spilling formula**

Try this formula - with your ranges for `years` and `values`

```
=LET(years,A2:A15,
values,IFERROR(B2:B15,0),
BYROW(years,LAMBDA(y,
             AVERAGE(FILTER(values,(years>y-10)*(years<=y))))))
```

It will spill down - no need to drag down.

[image]

Comment: what if the list (columns A and B) keeps expanding? your formula will return a spill error as it could not be dragged down

Comment: I added an update.

Answer (score 0):

`=LET(y,B1:B20,MAP(y,LAMBDA(a,AVERAGE(IFERROR(INDEX(y,MAX(1,ROW(a)-9),0):a,"")))))`

[image]